# Hive Delimiter 'field.delim' = '1'

Tags: hive, hiveql

What is the field delimiter if we create a table like this?

i am mentioning field.delim as 1. but on the file created when i load the data  to the table doesn't any visible character.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mydb`.`ct_ajay`(`col1` string, `col2` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1',
  'line.delim' = '
',
  'field.delim' = '1'
)
STORED AS
  INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'maprfs:/myfolder/ct_ajay'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime' = '1555387723'
)
```

Comment: _"on the file created ... no visible character"_ > there are ways to make invisible things visible. For instance, download the file from HDFS to your PC and inspect it with a decent editor such as Notepad++. Or if you are familiar with hex character codes, inspect the last record from an Edge node e.g. `hdfs dfs -tail /a/b/c | tail -n 1 | od -cx`

Comment: Pro tip: whenever Hive shows a weird behavior with literal char delimiters, define them with their **octal code** instead, like you see in all tutorials. I suspect your `'1'` was interpreted as the ASCII control character with code `\001`...